# Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку один блок скрывался а второй наоборот показывался на React

Tags: reactjs, useeffect, usestate

У меня есть блок reg-content и login-content, мне нужно чтобы по нажатию на кнопки Нет аккаунта Зарегистрироваться показывало страницу reg-content, и при нажатии на Зарегестрирован Войти - login content

```
import './App.css';
import {useState, useEffect, useTransition} from "react";

function App() {
const [page, setPage] = useState(1); // 0- login, 1 - reg
const [notify, setNotify] = useState("");
const [regBtnState, setRegBtnState] = useState("Регистрация");
const [loginBtnState, setLoginBtnState] = useState("Войти");

const [regUsername, setRegUsername] = useState("");
const [regEmail, setRegEmail] = useState("");
const [regPassword, setRegPassword] = useState("");
const [regPassword2, setRegPassword2] = useState("");

const [loginUsername, setLoginUsername] = useState("");
const [loginPassword, setLoginPassword] = useState("");

const handleLoginUsernameChange = (event) => setLoginUsername(event.target.value);
const handleLoginPasswordChange = (event) => setLoginPassword(event.target.value);

const handleRegUsernameChange = (event) => setRegUsername(event.target.value);
const handleRegEmailChange = (event) => setRegEmail(event.target.value);
const handleRegPasswordChange = (event) => setRegPassword(event.target.value);
const handleRegPassword2Change = (event) => setRegPassword2(event.target.value);

const onRegButtonClick = () =>
{
  if(regBtnState === "Загрузка") return; 
  setNotify("");

  const mainPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,100}$/;
  if(!regUsername.match(mainPattern)) 
  {
    setNotify("Логин должен состоять из латинских символов и цифр");
    return;
  }
  if(regUsername.length < 5 || regUsername.length > 20)
  {
    setNotify("Логин должен быть от 5 до 20 символов");
    return;
  }

  if (!regPassword.match(mainPattern))
  {
    setNotify("Пароль должен состоять из латинских символов и цифр");
    return;
  }
  if(regPassword.length < 6 || regPassword.length > 20)
  {
    setNotify("Пароль должен быть от 6 до 20 символов");
    return;
  }


  if(regPassword !== regPassword2) 
  {
    setNotify("Введеные пароли не совпадают");
    return;
  }

  const emailPattern = /^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$/;
  if(!regEmail.match(emailPattern)) 
  {
    setNotify("Некоректный Email");
    return;
  } 
  setRegBtnState("Загрузка");
  mp.trigger("CEF:CLIENT::REGISTER_BUTTON_CLICKED", regUsername, regPassword, regEmail);
}

const onLoginButtonClick = () => 
{
    if(loginBtnState === "Загрузка") return;
    setNotify("");

    const mainPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,100}$/;
    if(!loginUsername.match(mainPattern)) 
    {
      setNotify("Логин должен состоять из латинских символов и цифр");
      return;
    }
    if(loginUsername.length < 5 || loginUsername.length > 20)
    {
      setNotify("Логин должен быть от 5 до 20 символов");
      return;
    }

    if (!loginPassword.match(mainPattern))
    {
      setNotify("Пароль должен состоять из латинских символов и цифр");
      return;
    }
    if(loginPassword.length < 6 || loginPassword.length > 20)
    {
      setNotify("Пароль должен быть от 6 до 20 символов");
      return;
    }
    setLoginBtnState("Загрузка")
    mp.trigger("CEF:CLIENT::LOGIN_BUTTON_CLICKED", loginUsername, loginPassword);
}



useEffect( () =>{
    const showLoginPage = () => setPage(0);
    const showRegisterPage = () => setPage(1);

    const onRegisterUserExists = () =>
    {
      setRegBtnState("Регистрация");
      setNotify("");
    }

    const onLoginNotValidData = () =>
    {
      setLoginBtnState("Войти");
      setNotify("Неверный логин или пароль");
    }

    document.addEventListener('showLogin', showLoginPage);
    document.addEventListener('showRegister', showRegisterPage);
    document.addEventListener('registerUserExists', onRegisterUserExists);
    document.addEventListener('loginNotValidData', onLoginNotValidData);

    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('showLogin', showLoginPage);
        document.removeEventListener('showRegister', showRegisterPage);
        document.removeEventListener('registerUserExists', onRegisterUserExists);
        document.removeEventListener('loginNotValidData', onLoginNotValidData);
    }
    }, [])
return (
<div class="body">
  <div class="overlay">
  <div class="section">
     <div class="form-box">
        <div class="form-value">
          <div class="form" action="">
            {

              page === 0 ?
              <div class="login-content">
                   <div class="title">Авторизация</div>
                   <div class="title-description">Для продолжения войдите</div>
                   <div class="inputbox">
                      <div class="input-login-image"></div> 
                      <input placeholder="Логин" value={loginUsername} onChange={handleLoginUsernameChange}/>           
                   </div>
                   <div class="inputbox">
                      <div class="input-pass-image"></div>
                      <input type="password" placeholder="Пароль" vlaue={loginPassword} onChange={handleLoginPasswordChange}/>               
                   </div>
                   <div class="footnote">{notify}</div>
                   <div class="reg-butt">
                      <button className="button-reg" onClick={onLoginButtonClick}>{loginBtnState}</button>
                   </div>
                   <div class="login">
                      <p>Нет аккаунта <a>Зарегистрироваться</a></p> //при нажатии reg-content (page 1)
                   </div> 
              </div>
              : null
              
            }
            {

              page === 1 ?
              <div class="reg-content">
                  <div class="title">Регистрация</div>
                  <div class="title-description">Для продолжения зарегистрируйтесь</div>
                  <div class="inputbox">
                    <div class="input-login-image"></div>
                    <input placeholder="Логин" vlaue={regUsername} onChange={handleRegUsernameChange}/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="inputbox">
                    <div class="input-email-image"></div> 
                    <input placeholder="Email" vlaue={regEmail} onChange={handleRegEmailChange}/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="inputbox">
                    <div class="input-pass-image"></div> 
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Пароль" vlaue={regPassword} onChange={handleRegPasswordChange}/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="inputbox">
                    <div class="input-repass-image"></div> 
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Подтверждение пароля" vlaue={regPassword2} onChange={handleRegPassword2Change}/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="footnote">{notify}</div>
                  <div class="reg-butt">
                    <button className="button-reg" onClick={onRegButtonClick}>{regBtnState}</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="login">
                    <p>Зарегестрирован <a>Войти</a></p> //при нажатии login-content(page 0)
                  </div>
                </div>
                : null
            }
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

);
}

```
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать `setPage`, который определен в самом начале. Навесить на нужные элементы событие `onClick={() => setPage(0)}`

```js
import './App.css';
import {useState, useEffect, useTransition} from "react";

function App() {
const [page, setPage] = useState(1); // 0- login, 1 - reg
const [notify, setNotify] = useState("");
const [regBtnState, setRegBtnState] = useState("Регистрация");
const [loginBtnState, setLoginBtnState] = useState("Войти");

const [regUsername, setRegUsername] = useState("");
const [regEmail, setRegEmail] = useState("");
const [regPassword, setRegPassword] = useState("");
const [regPassword2, setRegPassword2] = useState("");

const [loginUsername, setLoginUsername] = useState("");
const [loginPassword, setLoginPassword] = useState("");

const handleLoginUsernameChange = (event) => setLoginUsername(event.target.value);
const handleLoginPasswordChange = (event) => setLoginPassword(event.target.value);

const handleRegUsernameChange = (event) => setRegUsername(event.target.value);
const handleRegEmailChange = (event) => setRegEmail(event.target.value);
const handleRegPasswordChange = (event) => setRegPassword(event.target.value);
const handleRegPassword2Change = (event) => setRegPassword2(event.target.value);

const onRegButtonClick = () =>
{
  if(regBtnState === "Загрузка") return; 
  setNotify("");

  const mainPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,100}$/;
  if(!regUsername.match(mainPattern)) 
  {
    setNotify("Логин должен состоять из латинских символов и цифр");
    return;
  }
  if(regUsername.length < 5 || regUsername.length > 20)
  {
    setNotify("Логин должен быть от 5 до 20 символов");
    return;
  }

  if (!regPassword.match(mainPattern))
  {
    setNotify("Пароль должен состоять из латинских символов и цифр");
    return;
  }
  if(regPassword.length < 6 || regPassword.length > 20)
  {
    setNotify("Пароль должен быть от 6 до 20 символов");
    return;
  }


  if(regPassword !== regPassword2) 
  {
    setNotify("Введеные пароли не совпадают");
    return;
  }

  const emailPattern = /^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$/;
  if(!regEmail.match(emailPattern)) 
  {
    setNotify("Некоректный Email");
    return;
  } 
  setRegBtnState("Загрузка");
  mp.trigger("CEF:CLIENT::REGISTER_BUTTON_CLICKED", regUsername, regPassword, regEmail);
}

const onLoginButtonClick = () => 
{
    if(loginBtnState === "Загрузка") return;
    setNotify("");

    const mainPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,100}$/;
    if(!loginUsername.match(mainPattern)) 
    {
      setNotify("Логин должен состоять из латинских символов и цифр");
      return;
    }
    if(loginUsername.length < 5 || loginUsername.length > 20)
    {
      setNotify("Логин должен быть от 5 до 20 символов");
      return;
    }

    if (!loginPassword.match(mainPattern))
    {
      setNotify("Пароль должен состоять из латинских символов и цифр");
      return;
    }
    if(loginPassword.length < 6 || loginPassword.length > 20)
    {
      setNotify("Пароль должен быть от 6 до 20 символов");
      return;
    }
    setLoginBtnState("Загрузка")
    mp.trigger("CEF:CLIENT::LOGIN_BUTTON_CLICKED", loginUsername, loginPassword);
}



useEffect( () =>{
    const showLoginPage = () => setPage(0);
    const showRegisterPage = () => setPage(1);

    const onRegisterUserExists = () =>
    {
      setRegBtnState("Регистрация");
      setNotify("");
    }

    const onLoginNotValidData = () =>
    {
      setLoginBtnState("Войти");
      setNotify("Неверный логин или пароль");
    }

    document.addEventListener('showLogin', showLoginPage);
    document.addEventListener('showRegister', showRegisterPage);
    document.addEventListener('registerUserExists', onRegisterUserExists);
    document.addEventListener('loginNotValidData', onLoginNotValidData);

    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('showLogin', showLoginPage);
        document.removeEventListener('showRegister', showRegisterPage);
        document.removeEventListener('registerUserExists', onRegisterUserExists);
        document.removeEventListener('loginNotValidData', onLoginNotValidData);
    }
    }, [])
return (
<div class="body">
  <div class="overlay">
  <div class="section">
     <div class="form-box">
        <div class="form-value">
          <div class="form" action="">
            {

              page === 0 ?
              <div class="login-content">
                   <div class="title">Авторизация</div>
                   <div class="title-description">Для продолжения войдите</div>
                   <div class="inputbox">
                      <div class="input-login-image"></div> 
                      <input placeholder="Логин" value={loginUsername} onChange={handleLoginUsernameChange}/>           
                   </div>
                   <div class="inputbox">
                      <div class="input-pass-image"></div>
                      <input type="password" placeholder="Пароль" vlaue={loginPassword} onChange={handleLoginPasswordChange}/>               
                   </div>
                   <div class="footnote">{notify}</div>
                   <div class="reg-butt">
                      <button className="button-reg" onClick={onLoginButtonClick}>{loginBtnState}</button>
                   </div>
                   <div class="login">
                      <p onClick={()=>setPage(1)}>Нет аккаунта <a>Зарегистрироваться</a></p> //при нажатии reg-content (page 1)
                   </div> 
              </div>
              : null
              
            }
            {

              page === 1 ?
              <div class="reg-content">
                  <div class="title">Регистрация</div>
                  <div class="title-description">Для продолжения зарегистрируйтесь</div>
                  <div class="inputbox">
                    <div class="input-login-image"></div>
                    <input placeholder="Логин" vlaue={regUsername} onChange={handleRegUsernameChange}/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="inputbox">
                    <div class="input-email-image"></div> 
                    <input placeholder="Email" vlaue={regEmail} onChange={handleRegEmailChange}/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="inputbox">
                    <div class="input-pass-image"></div> 
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Пароль" vlaue={regPassword} onChange={handleRegPasswordChange}/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="inputbox">
                    <div class="input-repass-image"></div> 
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Подтверждение пароля" vlaue={regPassword2} onChange={handleRegPassword2Change}/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="footnote">{notify}</div>
                  <div class="reg-butt">
                    <button className="button-reg" onClick={onRegButtonClick}>{regBtnState}</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="login">
                    <p onClick={()=>setPage(0)}>Зарегестрирован <a>Войти</a></p> //при нажатии login-content(page 0)
                  </div>
                </div>
                : null
            }
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Добавить:

```
const onLogClick = () => setPage(0); //страница, которая вам нужна;
```

- Добавить событие `onClick={onLoginClick}`, куда вам нужно.